# How to notify a subscriber before a subscription expires (using Commerce License)?

Tags: commerce

I'm using the [commerce license](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) module to sell subscriptions (a license in my case). I want to send an email to the subscriber before the license of a subscriber expires.

I found a code snippet in the module's issue queue, which I'm trying to test. So I granted a license to a user for 23 hours, and I want to get a notification message after running cron.

I'm new to Drupal coding, so I want to know what is wrong in my code (why it doesn't seem to work as I want to).

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function license_notif_cron() {
  $expires = strtotime('-1 day');
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_license')
    ->propertyCondition('status', COMMERCE_LICENSE_ACTIVE)
    ->propertyCondition('expires', 0, '<>')
    ->propertyCondition('expires', $expires, '>');
  $results = $query->execute();
  if (!empty($results['commerce_license'])) {
    $license_ids = array_keys($results['commerce_license']);
    drupal_set_message('licensce expires soon');
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's probably that you haven't replaced `// Now do something with this.` with code to do something...

Comment: I have replaced it with drupal_set_message function, so I'm planning to replace it with a mail function later.

Comment: Why is it wrapped in another function definition?

Comment: do you mean the notification message ?

Comment: I do indeed....

Comment: As I said I'm a newbie, I searched how to show notification message in google and I pasted it there there.* Implements of hook_init().
*/
function starting_drupal_dev_init() {
  drupal_set_message('licensce expires soon');
}
  }

Comment: It's a really good idea to learn the language first - copy/pasting as a beginner to php is never a good idea because you don't know what the code is doing. If you knew that little bit more about php you'd know that you've declared a function within a function (unusual in and of itself), & never invoked that function, so you essentially have a noop. Take out the bit you've pasted in, replace it with simply `drupal_set_message('licensce expires soon');` and your code has a better chance of working (I'm assuming that your module is named correctly and is installed, caches have been cleared, etc)

Comment: oh you are right, I know the php basic, but I copied the drupaL code without thinking. Now even if I cleared the cache and updated the code -see the question-, modules files ared named correctly nothing happen after running cron.